# Setting Static IP for eth1 on beaglebone black

Tags: linux, networking, ip

I need to set a static IP address on the eth1 interface after boot up. However, on bootup the device always has a different IP address than the one configured in the /etc/network/interfaces. This is a linux OS on beagle bone.

I am using the following linux version on beaglebone

```
root@beaglebone:/etc/network# cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.4.54-ti-r93 (root@a4-imx6q-wandboard-2gb) (gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10) ) #1 SMP Fri Mar 17 13:08:22 UTC 2017
```

The `/etc/network/interfaces` file is as below.

```
##connman: WiFi
#
#connmanctl
#connmanctl> tether wifi off
#connmanctl> enable wifi
#connmanctl> scan wifi
#connmanctl> services
#connmanctl> agent on
#connmanctl> connect wifi_*_managed_psk
#connmanctl> quit

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.3.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.3.0
    gateway 192.168.3.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

# Ethernet/RNDIS gadget (g_ether)
# Used by: /opt/scripts/boot/autoconfigure_usb0.sh
iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.7.2
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    network 192.168.7.0
    gateway 192.168.7.1
```

The ifconfig output is as follows

```
root@beaglebone:/etc/network# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 04:a3:16:e1:5d:39
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST DYNAMIC  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:173

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:c9:d0:29:e0:88
          inet addr:169.254.191.196  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::22c9:d0ff:fe29:e088/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST DYNAMIC  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:58 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:121 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:7438 (7.2 KiB)  TX bytes:42686 (41.6 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:250 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:250 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:19556 (19.0 KiB)  TX bytes:19556 (19.0 KiB)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 04:a3:16:e1:5d:3b
          inet addr:192.168.7.2  Bcast:192.168.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6a3:16ff:fee1:5d3b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:774 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:519 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:101935 (99.5 KiB)  TX bytes:93548 (91.3 KiB)

usb1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 04:a3:16:e1:5d:3e
          inet addr:192.168.6.2  Bcast:192.168.6.3  Mask:255.255.255.252
          inet6 addr: fe80::6a3:16ff:fee1:5d3e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:166 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:79 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:58485 (57.1 KiB)  TX bytes:16017 (15.6 KiB)
```

Comment: The syntax on the `interfaces` file seems correct. Did you run `/etc/init.d/networking restart`?

Comment: yes. I ran that as well as tried the
sudo ifconfig eth1 down
sudo ifconfig eth1 up

Comment: I would `grep` everything in `/etc` to find where `192.168.6.2` gets defined: `grep -r "192\.168\.6\.2" /etc`